# Limited access to the administration area by php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use codeigniter. I already have an permissions access levels `php` and `mysql` using sessions. 
I want to limit the pages that can be viewed by a registered admin depending on his access level. I have in database for each admin (each `id_relation` is for a admin) as image:

[image]

Each of this number in above database table is a page for example: (values subpages and service columns are `json`)

in mainpage: `1` is `page 1` , `3` is `page 3`, `5` is `page 5` and ...

**PHP: (I tried)**

```
$result = $this->db->get_where('access_level', array('id_relation'=>'6572242cc91f61b2f722e31ec55e3c7c'));
$data = array();
foreach($result->result() as $row){
    $data[] = $row->mainpage;       
}

if(in_array('1', $data)){
    echo 'access';
}else{
    echo 'not access';
} // out put is access
```

Now How do I set permissions for `subpage` for three-row that have `mainpage 1` for own pages? for example in the above database.

In id `1` user in `mainpage` has access to page `1` and in this mainpage(page 1) he has access to pages 3 , 4 , 6 in subpage and in each of subpages he has access to service 110. (They are connected together like a chain.)

It is also for the rest of the rows.
My html is as: http://jsfiddle.net/pbNt3/ and my php for insert data is as: http://pastebin.com/HpztqSwV

How to allow user access to any of the pages (mainpage and subpages ) and services in it subpages by php?

Comment: If you're storing arrays in your database, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @Waleed Khan - What is wrong? my html is as: http://jsfiddle.net/pbNt3/ and my php for insert data is as: http://pastebin.com/HpztqSwV

Comment: To expand on @WaleedKhan's comment: you should preferably be using separate cross-reference tables for fields where you are storing array data.

Comment: @Abhilash's : What it means? Please tell me an example?

Answer (score 0):

How about you run queries against your data base to see if something is returned from WHERE mainpage = 1.

Example :

```
SELECT......
FROM........
WHERE (your database flag) = ..........
```

I have the same set up on my application. I have 3 roles, student, staff, admin. I then use if else statements. Now from my understand of your DB only curtain people have access to pages, sub-pages and service. This can be done just by simply querying and seeing if a

```
return $whateveryou...
```

Example 2 :

```
function staffmember()
    {
        $username1 = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :user AND activated = 1";
        $staffmember = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql1);
        $staffmember->bindParam(':user', $username1);
        $staffmember->execute();
        $row = $staffmember->fetch();

        if($row['staffmember'] == 1)
        {
            return $staffmember;
        }
    }


    function is_admin()
    {
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :user";
    $is_admin = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
    $is_admin->bindParam(':user', $username);
    $is_admin->execute();   
    $row = $is_admin->fetch();

        if($row['admin'] == 1)
        {
            return $is_admin;
        }
    }
```

So then in the controller you do :

```
function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('staff_model');
        if($staffmember = $this->staff_model->staffmember()) //Checks for staff value == 1 
        {
            if($is_admin = $this->staff_model->is_admin()) // Checks for admin value == 1
        {
            $data3['main_content'] = 'admin_view';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data3);
        }else{ // If not admin == 1 
            $data['main_content'] = 'staff_homepage_view';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
        }
        }else{ // If not staff == 1
            $data1['main_content'] = 'student_homepage_view';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data1); 
        }
```

}

Hopefully you can take something use away from this.